# How to deal with slow unit tests while doing TDD in large c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, tdd, resharper

Using visual studio 2017 NUnit and the resharper test runner, how do you maintain a good unit test speed when doing TDD in a large c# project (5000+) tests. Even if each of those tests takes only 5ms, that's 25 seconds which is quite slow for a TDD cycle.

Our tests don't call the database nor do they call external web services. They only test business logic.

I have found that using moq, doing a Mock.Setup() alone takes almost 1ms. Since we might have a few moq setups call per tests, this is the primary culprit for our slow unit tests.

Is there any way to speed up unit tests speed? Is there any mocking libraries faster than moq? Or maybe another test runner that is faster?

Comment: 25s for 5000 tests is quite reasonable, to my mind anyway. One way would be to break your solution up, perhaps take common/infrastructure things out into reusable NuGet packages. Then the total unit test time won't decrease but developers will typically deal with a component at a time instead.

Comment: I'll preface this by saying I've never done TDD, but I have unit tested often. The impression I always got from "tests should run quickly" in my readings was that tests shouldn't take hours, maybe not even minutes, to run. Long running tests encourage not running tests. Waiting 25 seconds is not a long time to wait, IMO.

Comment: Which testing framework are you using? Some support running tests in parallel.

Comment: That is a good idea, I am using Nunit and it does support parallel testing, I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: Most NUnit runners also support only running the affected tests, so it shouldn't run anywhere near the 5000 for each change.  A really great tool for TDD, especially for smaller solutions, is NCrunch, as it annotates your code live as you type, based on test results. Not free though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are going down the wrong rabbit whole: the **overall** runtime of all your unit tests is still in a very reasonable range!

While doing development (maybe using TDD) you don't care about *all* unit tests. You only care about those that are relevant to the current component/package/... !

As in: when you make a change in file `A`, you probably want to (manually) run all unit tests for the directory `A` lives in. You make another small change, you run these tests again.

Then, later on, when you think: "I am done for now", *then* you invoke all unit tests, to ensure you didn't break something on the other end of the building by rearranging the furniture in that room over here.

So, the answer is: you are fine, don't worry.

We have 5000+ Java unit tests. On our fastest build server, it can take about 10 minutes to work them all. But that is still ok. The backend build still comes back after 20 minutes and tells us "broken" or "all fine". Why? Because the build server only kicks in when I decide that my change set is complete, and I push it to the server.

When those 25 seconds are a problem for, then because you are running *all* tests too often because you trigger them manually. Now: rather spend your energy figuring clever ways to only run the *relevant* tests when working on a specific problems in an efficient way. (in Java with JUnit, it is easy: I click on the current package, and go "run all tests in here)

Comment: If you're on an Enterprise SKU with Visual Studio, then to test only what you're working on, you can enable the Live Unit Testing feature for the area of code where you're working.  NCrunch (as mentioned in comments above) is another similar tool for the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Consider getting rid of most tests you have.**

While I don't have a lot of experience with unit testing and TDD, the limited experience I **do** have points to most unit tests being quite useless. And there are experienced people that support my opinion, as an example of this viewpoint, consider these two articles:

- https://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf
- https://rbcs-us.com/documents/Segue.pdf

I'm not sure about continuity of this discussion (i.e. who was the first to bring it up), but here a couple of people who reference the article above and agree with it, and maybe add a couple of their own points:

- https://medium.com/pacroy/why-most-unit-testing-is-waste-tests-dont-improve-quality-developers-do-47a8584f79ab
- https://techbeacon.com/1-unit-testing-best-practice-stop-doing-it

Do note, that the argument is not about testing at all, it's about extensive unit-tests as opposed to integration and system-level testing.

Comment: The first article is highly controversial. One can argue that the cost of writing certain types of unit tests outweighs the benefit, but your opening statement is too broad to be correct.

Comment: @Stijn of course it's controversial, if the idea was widely acknowledged as truth, everyone would follow it. Also, none of the articles argues to ban unit tests, just stop writing thousands of them and put your focus into integration and system tests.

Comment: With integration tests and system tests you see *IF* your code is working or not, but finding out *where* the code error is, is very hard.  Unit tests tell you very specifically what is not working, it answers the *where* part.  So you need both, and then @ghostcat 's answer is a very good one. Test only what you need, but keep all of them, they're your regression suite.

Comment: @TerjeSandstrøm not really. "Clean" unit-tests mock out dependencies, so if class A works fine with specific parameters, and class B works fine with specific parameters doesn't mean the place where they intersect works fine with those same parameters as well. Unit tests won't catch the error with intersection by design - there's no class B in class A tests, and no class A in class B tests, only mocks

Comment: "Clean" unit tests don't necessarily mock out dependencies. See the Classic vs Mockist approaches to TDD. There is a lot of debate on this.